# How to easily purge custom shared instances in cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, purge

I'm doing a small Cocos2d-x project, where I've been inspired by the "singleton" pattern implemented by `CCDirector::sharedDirector()` method and other shared instances in Cocos2d-x. For instance, in `CCDirector.cpp` we have

```
static CCDisplayLinkDirector *s_SharedDirector = NULL;

// ...

CCDirector* CCDirector::sharedDirector(void)
{
    if (!s_SharedDirector)
    {
        s_SharedDirector = new CCDisplayLinkDirector();
        s_SharedDirector->init();
    }

    return s_SharedDirector;
}

void CCDirector::purgeDirector()
{
    // cleanup scheduler
    getScheduler()->unscheduleAll();

    // ...

    // delete CCDirector
    release();
}
```

The `purgeDirector()` method purges all the other shared instances, like shared animation cache, shared sprite frame cache and so on - all cast in the same mold. I'd like to do a couple of these myself, like a shared game lobby.

I'd rather not modify CCDirector, since it is definitely subject to change.

Are there any natural place I could put my purge code? Are there possibilities for ringing a callback when `cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->end()` is called or similar? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a serious "Douh!" moment, I realized that purging of custom singletons would most easily be placed in the `AppDelegate::~AppDelegate()` destructor, where `AppDelegate` is provided in the cocos2d-x Xcode template. So I did.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, maybe you shouldn't get "inspired" by the Singleton pattern in the first place.

Yes, they're arguably easy to pick up and are tempting but they're also bad design in 99% of all cases (including most of cocos2d's Singletons). Especially since you said "a couple of these".

A Singleton is essentially a container for global variables. Global variables (like Singletons) are something best avoided **unless** they are completely decoupled from all other classes and serve a single purpose. The NSFileManager being a good example, or the SimpleAudioEngine singleton.

A better design uses a tree-like structure of dependent and contained objects, not unlike the hierarchy of nodes in a scene. In a singleton-less design it becomes trivial to "purge" objects. Once you purge the parent-most object handling a specific task (ie a scene) then all the descendant objects are automatically purged along with it - provided that there aren't any object lifetime (memory management) bugs in the code.

Each class should be responsible for creating and freeing the object it contains. By "contain" I mean instance pointers as member variables or sometimes array or dictionary member variables containing instance pointers.

This article explains [C++ object life cycles](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS62/L03slides/lecture.html) well and to the point. But it's only a start.

Comment: thanks for your input! I totally agree about the down sides of the Singleton pattern. Reconsidering my needs, I'm thinking of going for one singleton: a 'GameLobby' which will do all the talking with the server side. This is desirable, because the player might have multiple games going at once, and so a central instance could both build up lists of active games, as well as push game data to the 'Game' class. I'll think it over once more.